# How to compare $E[\frac{X_i}{\sqrt{\sum_{i} X_i^2}}]$ and $\frac{E[X_{i}]}{E[\sqrt{\sum_{i} X_i^2}]}$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

I have a set of random variables $X_{i}\sim N(\mu_{i},\sigma_{i}^{2}), i\in[1,L]$, now I want to calculate the following expectation
$$E[\frac{X_i}{\sqrt{\sum_{i} X_i^2}}]$$
and compare it with
$$\frac{E[X_{i}]}{E[\sqrt{\sum_{i} X_i^2}]}$$
My guess is
$$E[\frac{X_i}{\sqrt{\sum_{i} X_i^2}}] \geq \frac{E[X_{i}]}{E[\sqrt{\sum_{i} X_i^2}]}$$
but I have no clues to solve this problem.

Can anyone provide me with some hints to solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using Jensen´s inequality? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality

Comment: @WeierstraßRamirez I tried to use Jensen´s inequality but the function is not convex or concave. Maybe I need to transform the original function but I cannot come up with a way to do it.